# When exactly are quadratic objective functions polynomial time solvable

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

I'm considering quadratic programming problems of the form:

$$ \max x^tQx+Bx$$

subject to the linear constraint

$$ Ax \le b $$
I read that if is the case that

$$ x^tQx + Bx \ge 0 \ \forall x$$
or 
$$ x^tQx + Bx \le 0 \ \forall x$$

Then the objective can be declared as positive semidefinite and negative semidefinite respectively.

Furthermore if positive semidefinite, the solution to the program can be recovered in polynomial time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming#Complexity

I don't think I understand what they mean. Consider the following 0-1 Integer Program

$$ \max \left(x_1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2  + \left(x_2 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2  + \left(x_3 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2  ... \left(x_n - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2  $$

$$ Ax \le b $$

This amounts to "find the point furthest away from the center of n-dimensional unit cube subject to linear constraints."

The Hessian of our objective function is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 \ 0 \ ... \ 0 \\ 0 \ 2 \ ... \ 0 \\ \vdots \ \vdots  \ \ddots  \ \vdots \\ 0 \ 0 \ ... \ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

Which is clearly positive semi-definite. (Again our objective function is a sum of squares so it is always greater than or equal to 0).

But if this could be solved in polynomial time, then the decision problem of 0-1 integer programming, does there exist a solution A to the problem instance of 0-1 integr programming Q, could be solved in polynomial time lets say P(n).

Then it follows that in P(n)log(n) (by binary search on the max value of objective function) we could solve 0-1 integer programming, P=NP... the world collapses and I get a million bucks and move to Antarctica.

Obviously, thats ridiculous. So what mistake did I make in that analysis?

Comment: It might be the case that my mistake is that positive semidefinite objectives can only be minimized, and not necessarily maximized

Comment: Your mistake is bringing $\{0,1\}$ into it. That changes everything. The Wikipedia article does not address that, it refers only to the continuous case.

Comment: @MichaelGrant a 0-1 integer program can be rewritten as does there exist an integer vector satisfying constraints Ax<=b. 0 <= x <= 1, this becomes the quadratic program max: (x -1/2)^2, Ax <= b. A rapid solution to the latter allows you to solve the originally with only log(obj value) more queries

Comment: Again, that is simply not the model being addressed in the Wikipedia article. The article deals only with continuous variables.

Comment: But that's fine, since I have changed the problem into a purely continuous one by the transformations highlighted

Comment: Ah, OK, I see what you're trying to do. Two problems. First, I do not believe your conversion to a QP is equivalent. Furthermore, the Wikipedia article is referring to the *minimization* of a convex quadratic. Your model is the *maximization* of a convex quadratic, which is equivalent to the minimization of a concave quadratic. That is in the NP-hard category referred to in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: The x are free to be anything between 0 and 1 but the choice of objective function ensures they will be only maximized at an integer point, and any integer point will satisfy.

Comment: That simply is not the case. The constraints may prevent them from ever reaching the integer values.

Comment: @MichaelGrant ah that sums it up then

Comment: @MichaelGrant, correct. if an integer isn't found in the QP then there is no solution to the associated 0-1 ILP

Comment: And nothing in your reformulation prevents the optimal values of $x$ being *larger* than 1 or *smaller* than 0 (again, unless $Ax\leq b$ already does so.)

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the issue of your reduction from a 0,1 to a continuous problem, which I didn't quite follow but seems highly suspicious, there is a far more basic issue. The quadratic **minimization** problem is polynomially solvable if $Q$ is positive semidefinite, but here you have a **maximization** problem.